# how to get android build system to create jar files?

Tags: android, build, jar

I'm writing a bound Service class for android.  In addition, I thought I'd provide a client class that would wrap all the Handler/Messenger/Bundle stuff into an easy to use API.  When I build this project, I want it to build the Service into an .apk and the client class into a .jar file that I can use in other projects.  Is that possible?  I'd prefer to do it in a way that would work with Eclipse or Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a [Shared Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).  From the docs:

> You can also designate an Android project as a library project, which allows it to be shared with other projects that depend on it. Once an Android project is designated as a library project, it cannot be installed onto a device.

There's a detailed how-to on the page, but the short version is that once you have separate projects for the app and the library, right click on the library's project, go to Properties > Android, and select the "Is Library" checkbox.

To reference it, from the application's project, go to Properties > Android, and in the library section, click "Add" and choose your library.

Comment: Note that, as of the time of this writing, Android library projects cannot be packaged as redistributable JARs. That is being worked on, and should be available soonish (I hope I hope I hope). That being said, going with an Android library project *is* the right direction.

Comment: I moved it to a library project and the build did produce a jar.  Are you saying that jar is not redistributable?  Why not?

Comment: I believe it is redistributable. The library projects used to link directly to the source code, but with one of the recent sdk updates, it has switched over to just referencing this jar.